# blazor component not updating | core3.0

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Trying to use the solution generated by the latest templates.

- Having a service whih keeps the list of string.
- injecting the service in both MainLayout.razor and NavMenu.razor
- The servie has simple methods viz Add, Remove, Items
- In the MainLayout, using the OnInitializedAsync() adding some items
  like following

.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this.svc.Add("string one");
            this.svc.Add("string two");
        });
         await Task.Run(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
```

- In the html fragment of NavMenu.razor, i am simple trying to print

  #### @svc.Items.Count
- With above code i am not seeing the count getting updated/refreshed,
  i can have another button handler in MainLayout as well to call the
  svc.Add method , but count does not get updated.
- **Only** when i try to have some btn handler in the navMenu.razor the blazor re-renders itself

```html
<button @onclick="SetCurrentTime"> Time </button>
    <h4>@time</h4>
        
    void SetCurrentTime()
            {
                time = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
```

github repo for this problem: (hit AddString and counter should increment) https://github.com/pkaushik23/mycodeshares/tree/master/CheckRefreshBlazor

[image]

Comment: Easy on the `Task.Run()` stuff. You should probably remove all of that and try again.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman, as this was a sample code, but in reality i would be getting that from some api call. The await/asyn stuf is not necessary there ? Also, as I have a service in picture some other component would call the **Add** method on the service and i want my navBar component to show updated list.

Comment: client-side you don't have threads so Task.Run() can't be useful, it could only deadlock things.

Comment: No repro. Go and create a [mcve] and make sure it shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i am still learning. about task, i got confused by this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#lifecycle-methods. Please can you advise if you know where can i do the MRE.

Comment: In Visual Studio: File, New Project, Blazor App, ...

Comment: :) i guess i sould learn to articulate myself better. I meant, how to share with some who can run and see.otherwise the code is same what i mentioned originally.

Comment: @HenkHolterman check this repo : https://github.com/pkaushik23/mycodeshares

Comment: OK, you call Add() from Index, which renders _after_ the NavMenu. And that menu doesn't have a reason to update again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `NameService` should to notify changes. Learn about it on  [Invoke component methods externally to update state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state)

For your service code, something like:

```
public class StringService
{
    public event Func<string, Task> Notify;
    public List<string> Names { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public void Add(string s)
    {
        this.Names.Add(s);
        if (Notify != null)
        {
            await Notify.Invoke(s);
        }            
    }
}
```

on your components:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    this.svc.Notify += OnNotify;
}

public async Task OnNotify(string s)
{
    await InvokeAsync(() =>
    {            
        StateHasChanged();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dani, for my understanding please. What it means is that if the event was raised from within a component then the "SynchronizationContext " would have taken care of it, right?

Comment: do you know why calling "StateHasChanged()" in the Index.razor's Add() method does not have the same affect as  triggering an event based on some external activity. TIA

Comment: I assume, stateHasChanged is only responsible for the current component where it is being called and does not bubble up for full hierarchy. Many thanks to you 

Comment: Explained by Daniel Roth (MS Also .Net team):https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/420#issuecomment-501385940